# What does taking the logarithm of a variable mean?

Tags: statistics, logarithms, normal-distribution

Question with regards to taking the logarithm of a variable (Statistics Question)

Say you have a bar graph displaying data for an example "Cost of Computer Orders by the Population" and you are trying to analyze the data and find a distribution. The information does not indicate anything so you take the logarithm of the variable and the graph then resembles a normal distribution. What does taking the logarithm of the variable indicate?

Comment: It's bad etiquette to post the same question on two SE sites simultaneously...

Comment: what do you mean by "the normal distribution basically means the mean", @masterminder

Comment: Cross-post: http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/48563

Comment: I accidentally posted on stackoverflow thinking I posted to math.stackexchange. I was not aware there was a stats forum as well so I posted it to that one because it seemed more appropriate.

My apologies

Comment: @RustynYazdanpour cleared it up now that did not make sense